# Download folder from google drive using Cmd/powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

i want to download a folder from google drive (or any other cloud storage if it's more easy) with powershell or cmd without download wget/curl.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of Google Drive, no its not possible.
However, you have the REST-API https://developers.google.com/drive/